# 3D triangulation of the surface by points

Tags: search, multidimensional-array, surface, triangulation

I have an array of 3D points. And according to them, you need to build a triangulation only on the surface of the body, as shown in the [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYXa3.png). Which method is best to use? It will be great if you explain how your proposed method works.

Delaunay's triangulation didn't help

Answer (score 0):

If c++ is fine, you can find in the [CGAL](https://www.cgal.org) library [the advancing front surface reconstruction](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Advancing_front_surface_reconstruction/index.html) package.

Comment: It would be desirable for me to realize my own. Since my project is in Delphi.